# Circuit to remove dc and extract AC signal

Tags: power-electronics

I just started working in the Power Electronics domain and I am learning and understanding the concepts of electrical and electronic circuits.

Attached is the circuit diagram I am trying to understand and design.

At the `Point_of_Interest`, I want a circuit that extracts the AC signal (Sinusoidal 50V 60Hz in this case).  Is it possible to design such a circuit?  If so, can anyone please suggest me how to extract this signal?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Coupling capacitor

Comment: What are you going to do with the AC? Is it just a signal to you that you want to analyze? Or do you want to allow the AC to get through so you can power something with it? If you just want the signal, you can use a capacitor in series with your detector. Try googling "DC blocking capacitor."

Comment: Alternative name for this application: "blocking capacitor".

Comment: Thanks for the resposes. @ mkeith: I want to extract this AC signal and find its peak-to-peak, rms and frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a coupling capacitor or a high pass filter
The capacitor will block the DC but AC will pass.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just want to add the comment for the OP that the R and C together form a low pass filter. The smaller the R is, the larger C will need to be in order to pass 50 Hz. If R becomes too small, C will become impractically large at 50 Hz. This is why I was asking what you want to do with the AC.

Comment: And, btw, this traditionally how the "AC" mode is implemented in oscilloscopes.